# Кеширование на php

Tags: php, кэширование

Вот такой пример: когда пользователь авторизуется, идёт проверка на то, существует ли его кеш данных или нет, если нет, то идёт выборка из базы и запись в кеш. Далее все изменения происходят в кеше. Как сделать обновление из кеша в базу данных, ведь нужно как-то периодически сохранять новые значения, ибо кеш, как известно, не вечен?

Есть такой вариант: поставить демона (cron) на пробежку по всем пользователям и если он видит, что данные изменились, то обновляет учётную запись в базе данных. Проверку сделать, к примеру, раз в 2 или 1 минуту с учётом лимита.

Не знаю, пойдёт ли такой вариант или нет, является ли оптимальным или нет, возможно есть какие-нибудь идеи?

**Добавление.**

Вопрос более чем актуален. Одно из предложений: крон не надо, просто в кешевой таблице делается дополнительное поле - счетчик проверок и ставится, например, при каждом 1000 запросе скидывать данные в базу и счетчик после этого обнуляется. Это гораздо лучшее решение. Более гибкое, т.к. можно число 1000 менять по вкусу и не дает пиковой нагрузки, как при запуске через крон.

Answer (score 3):

Мое предложение - это nosql в sql. Сделайте одну табличку с двумя полями и юзайте. Такая система также легко масштабируема. Хотя на практике именно такую схему я не реализовывал. Осуществлял проекты с одним redis, redis + oracle, redis + mysql. У redis есть возможность сохранять на диск, но он ограничен оперативной памятью.

Был проект: личный кабинет пользователя интернет услугами провайдера, так там в redis кроме справочников ничего не вошло.

Если у Вас вся бизнес логика помещается в 8 гб оперативной памяти сервера, ну или в 2х8 гб двух серверов, то можно только redis, но опять же 16 гб не нагрузят излишне mysql при правильном проектировании.

Многие наивно полагают, что добавив кеш и запихнув туда все, они решат все свои проблемы. Не хочу никого оскорблять, но если на тестах уже не завалится, то потом будет неисправимая ситуация (предусмотрите отключение и работу без кеша, на всякий пожарный).

А при схеме с базой и кешем я посоветую следующее (из имеющегося опыта, около 4 проектов, 4 делаю сейчас, пожтому около):

1. Разработайте даталогическую модель для всей бизнес логики. Старайтесь разрабатывать так, чтобы в будущем не было перемешивающихся операций insert,update и select. Поясню: если происходит только insert, то избавляйте таблицу от индексов. Старайтесь не использовать update или лучше делайте по принципу обвновить одно поле (foreign key), а в другой таблице создать новое поле.
       К примеру: одни ребята создали проект, который падал постоянно из-за больших нагрузок (у них 4х звенная архитектура с апп сервером на делфи, падал на уровне 4 звена - б.д. не справлялась с наплывом огромных транзакций с update). Решили тоже все кешировать, но толку мало вышло. Сослались на неумение проектировать в nosql. А все тормоза были на update в обыной базе, а nosql не справлялся с объемом (прошу правильно понять под объемом оперативную память). Помогал им перепроэктировать подход к хранению данных, реляционность у них на 5 из 5 была: посоветовал им избавиться от update и заменить все на insert. Пока работает и без redis, хотя он тоже есть но для промежуточного мусора (справочники и настройки).
2. Станет теперь более ясная картина, сколько данных гоняется, что несложно даже в байтах просчитать, помноженное на активность и количество пользователей. Вот тут и видно сразу, что ложить в кеш и когда он переполнится и все рухнет. Может туда только неизменяемые справочники загонять можно будет, а вот все ассоциации не влезут. Видел ребят, которые пихают все из базы в redis, моя теория сработала, у них все летало, до поры, а потом рухнуло. К тому же лучше оптимизировать некоторые моменты в базе. 
       А пришли эти ребята к такому решению на основании успешного опыта с предыдущим проектом, вот только глазами не туда смотрели, они не данные из базы туда кешировали а уже отдаваемый пользователю контент (html страницы).
3. Один только redis или memcash не использовать. Ну или же на крайняк используйте за ними базу с таблицами без индексов, insert будет летать. А стартоваться будет долговато, но смотря что приоритетнее.

P.S.: Опыт есть, но в моих ответах не хватает терминологии и связанности предложений из-за того что мысли обгоняют печатаемый текст, так что сори за орфографию.

Answer (score 1):

Классикой жанра является [memcached](http://memcached.org/). Используйте его. Что же до периодического сохранения, то таким способом вы снижаете надёжность: если что-то в системе случиться... кэш ваш упадёт, пропадёт связь с базой или ещё чего и все данные пропадут, хотя пользователя вы уже уверили, что всё сделано. Так что это может быть не самой лучшей идеей, если данные эти имеют хоть какое-то значение для пользователей.

Comment: Тоже остановили свой выбор на memcached. Но программист знает его поверхностно, не подскажете, где можно найти специалистов, которые помогут разобраться с memcached? Или специализированный форум, с адекватными людьми. Каждый раз вопрос тут писать не удобно, хочется создать отдельную тему и там вести дискуссию, что и как лучше сделать. Сам я геймдизайнер, наш проект http://fgods.ru, его и хотим переписать на memcached. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не уверен, что такая схема вообще подходит для написания игрового сервера. Думаю, будет тормозить под нагрузкой, точнее, время отклика будет неудовлетворительным.

Answer (score 1):

Вашу задачу очень изящно решает [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Вариант с демоном - костыль. Который будет сильно грузить систему, как только количество пользователей превысит определенный предел.

А вообще изменения должны проводиться не в кеше, а в базе данных и, возможно, в кеше, а чтобы кеш выполнял свою функцию, нужно реализовать парадигму безгоночного кеширования: когда установкой и обновлением кеша занимается один процесс (такие решения есть в готовом виде на github.com).